# How do I add links to my menu and get the content to show text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am using this current vertical menu that I want to use for my site. I am wondering how do I get the menu so that when I check the button on the left hand side, it makes the tab active, and displays information (text) on the right content div. I want each to have some different info.

CODE:

```js
 $(function() {

             var verticalNavigation = new
         SSDSystem.VerticalNavigation();
             verticalNavigation.init();

     });
```

```css
body {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #666;
     font-family: "Open sans", Sans-serif;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0
    }

    a {
     text-decoration: none
    }

    h1 {
     margin-top: 0
    }

    #contentWrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: relative
    }

    #contentLeft {
     z-index: 10;
     width: 250px;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-color: #283c51
    }

    #contentRight {
     padding: 1.3rem 2rem;
     margin-left: 250px
    }

    #leftNavigation {
     margin: 2rem 0
    }

    #leftNavigation,
    #leftNavigation li ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0
    }

    #leftNavigation li a {
     font-size: 0.875rem;
     display: block;
     padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0.8rem 3rem;
     color: #adadad;
     border-bottom: solid 1px #395673;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease;
     transition: color 0.2s ease
    }

    #leftNavigation li a,
    #leftNavigation li a .leftNavIcon {
     line-height: 120%
    }

    #leftNavigation li a .leftNavIcon {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 3rem;
     padding: 0.8rem 0;
     text-align: center
    }

    #leftNavigation li a:hover {
     color: #fff
    }

    #leftNavigation li ul {
     display: none;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: #17232f
    }

    #leftNavigation li ul li a {
     border-bottom: solid 1px #233547
    }

    #leftNavigation li ul li:last-child a {
     border-bottom: none
    }

    #leftNavigation li ul li.active a {
     color: #fff
    }

    #leftNavigation li.active>a {
     color: #fff
    }

    #leftNavigation li.active ul {
     display: block
    }

    #leftNavigation>li.active {
     background-color: #427c97
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <div id="contentLeft">
    <ul id="leftNavigation">
      <li class="active"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"><br></i>Promeion</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#Athemia"><i class="fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 2 </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 4 </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 6 </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 6 </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-down leftNavIcon"></i> Menu 7 </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> World Details & Rules </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right leftNavIcon"></i> Ranks & Commands </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="contentRight">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/object/VerticalNavigation.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery hide() and show(). When you click a link on the side, you hide() the current `<div>` and then show() the `<div>` that they clicked.

Tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<div>` containers with ID attribute and link to them from menu items.

**Sample:**

```
<a href="#cont-1"> Your Text Here </a>
<div id="cont-1"> Your Content Here </div>
```

By clicking the menu items you will need some javascript.
See solution here [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aani/wnnt3v96/). 
Hope this will help.

Comment: This works thanks! I have another question, the menu is not showing some of the top tab. It is behind my navbar, how can I pull it down? Also the div content box is somewhat behind the menu, how can I change it to finish short of it?

Comment: I'm not fully understand your question. Can you describe in more details ? What you have behind your navbar ?

Comment: So, the menu that I have just added in (the blue one that you edited the code), is behind the navbar, and I would like to pull it down so that the top of the new blue menu lines up with the bottom of the navbar. And the div content box is large of the left, and I want it to be centered in the space between the new blue menu and the other modules on the right.

Comment: I understand :) Seems you have fixed navbar and I think I know what is the problem with centering. I need your whole code to understand which styles you have used, to provide right and optimal solution. Can you upload you code on live server or provide in other way as its comfortable for you.

Comment: I have updated code here https://jsfiddle.net/wnnt3v96/1/, please look is it what you want ? Let me know if have questions.

Comment: Thanks that has improved it. I had to push up the left menu though, from 50px to 30px and now that looks fine. It looks great now, except the right side has been pulled across and the little menu down the bottom is now messing up, here is a picture to show you what I mean. https://gyazo.com/07d9f9ac8d5186e8aa5899b711b052fd

Also, how do I get the div content to centre inside the div? Cheers.

Comment: Also, how do I make it so the div content box becomes scrollable so I can scroll to more content? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry another question, when I click a menu button it opens up the submenus, how can I make it so the submenus stay open unless the menu is clicked again to close?

Comment: 1) To center <div> content you need to set width and use margin:0 auto;

Comment: 2) To make <div> scrollable, you need to set height and use overflow:auto

Comment: .classname { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; } // center div
.classname { width: 100%; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; } // center responsive div
.classname { height: 400px; overflow: auto; } // add scroll

Comment: Regarding right side that has been pulled down, this is depending on your css styles, provide me picture how everything should look in right way, that I can help you.  

And clarify what you need with menu, I'm not quite understand.

Comment: Regarding the little menu, this is how it looks normally: https://gyazo.com/5a909b206878e26e8449182179b214cd

Comment: what do I do to implement the .classname? Do I rename the classname to something?

Comment: For the sub menu on the blue menu on the left, I would like it so that the the submenu items e.g. World Details & Rules don't close if you click on something else like menu 2. For it to close the World Details & rules as well as Ranks & Commands, you would have to click the main menu 1 button, the button which you click to change div content.

Comment: I have changed example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wnnt3v96/5/ 

Yes insted of .classname you need to use css selector ( id, class ... )

Comment: Thanks so much! How can I fix the problem with the little menu down the bottom?

How it looks currently: https://gyazo.com/fccb2d14f4c5af4ff46263fd6f012f6f

How it should look: https://gyazo.com/5a909b206878e26e8449182179b214cd

Comment: Nevermind I have figured this out! It was just an issue with the site, because I am using enjin (website) and they had a .container css property already, so I just renamed it to .containr and changed it in the html. Thanks so so so much for the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad that could be helpful :)
For little menu try to set "width", or use "float" to positioning elements. 
Or provide live url that I can check what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Hey again, is there a way I can make it so the category like 'Promeion' has another sub category like 'survival' and 'hardcore' that when you click on it, would open up different 'World Details & Rules' as well as 'ranks and commands' tabs for each? Thanks!